# Getting at array elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    // print_r($_POST['row']); // Works perfectly
    echo $_POST['row[1][2]'];
}
?>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<?php 
$num_of_days_in_month=3;
for($i = 1; $i<= $num_of_days_in_month; $i ++) {
for($j = 1; $j <= 4; $j++) {
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"row[$i][$j]\" />";
if ($j ==4) {
    echo "<br>";
}
}
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I am trying to echo row 1, column 2 and the output is blank.

Anyone know why?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: If you like to see what came through $_POST just dump all ... with ; echo "<pre>".vardump($_POST)."</pre>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexing is wrong, try this

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    echo $_POST['row'][1];
    echo $_POST['row'][2];
}
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    echo $_POST['row'][1][2];
}
?>
```

Comment: Positive answered first so I gave it to him/her.

Comment: @jimdif I answered first, check the time :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Yes, you answered first but you put the correct answer after mine. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`echo $_POST['row'][1][2];`